# Getting "Unable to reach app. Please try again" in TEAMS Bot

Tags: botframework

I have developed a TEAMS based bot, which will authenticate the user to get the values from AD. As soon as, I click sign-in button in the interactive card, I get the popup to allow the bot to access my details. As soon as the popup is closed, I get "Unable to reach app".

[image]

When I used the TEAMS in browser, I captured the below error.

502 Bad Gateway
https://apac.ng.msg.teams.microsoft.com/v1/agents/XXXXXXXXX/invoke

{
"errorCode": 1008,
"message": "Error when processing invoke response: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.",
"standardizedError": {
"errorCode": 1008,
"errorSubCode": 1,
"errorDescription": "Error when processing invoke response: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."
}
}

I have no clue about this error. Whether anyone faced this issue before?